# C language calling nested function

Tags: c, gcc

I know that C does not support nested functions and it's only a gcc extension. But even so, this behavior is strange.

It seems like the nested functions can be called only once; the second calling causes SIGSEV, and sometimes SIGILL. I want nested functions for structures like stack. On stack, I would be able to define functions like pop, push, etc., which I will assign with nested functions, which will call normal functions with reference, which I will get. This function is like a constructor, or initializer. But this code is enough to simulate my problem.

When generate function assigns innerFunction into struct, second calling causes an error. If the assignment is to test function, second calling is ok.

Where is the problem, please? In gcc documentation, it says that as long as you have inner function address, you can access this function and nested function has access into all variables defined above.

```
typedef struct A A;

struct A {
    void (*foo)();
};

void test() {
  printf("test\n");
}

void generate(A* a) {

    void innerTest(){
       test();
    }

    a->foo = &innerTest;
}


int main() {

    A a;
    generate(&a);

    a.foo();
    a.foo();
};
```

Comment: What is your problem? I correctly compiled and executed your code.

Comment: I believe nested functions are non conforming. Even though it may work

Comment: The [documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Nested-Functions.html#Nested-Functions) actually says "*If you try to call the nested function through its address after the containing function exits, all hell breaks loose.*"

Comment: This  code causes segment fault and print "test"  only once. Tested with c99 and c11 with same gcc version.  But output should contains "test"  twice

Comment: Does the GCC manual say what the output should contain? If what you see is not what the manual says, then you have an issue with the GCC developers. And c99 and c11 say "Just Don't Do That" - you're well outside what they promise.

Comment: @self: The question already acknowledges that nested functions are a gcc extension, not defined by the C standard.

Answer (score 0):

Do not allow pointers to inner functions to escape the stack frame they were created on. This yields undefined behavior.

The code generated places a trampoline on the stack. With the particular construct you have created, the trampoline got overwritten with your first call to the function so it failed at the second call to the function.

<strike>I personally am annoyed that it invokes that behavior without a closure to care about, but that's what it does.</strike> Oh wait I get it. your example works because in pairing it down this far you accidentally reduced it to working code (see acorngal's comment). Your real code accesses the pointer to structure labelled a and so does force a closure and therefore a trampoline. You cannot do this stunt in C; when doing OO programming you must pass the equivalent to the `this` pointer yourself.

Comment: The trampoline is created, when the address of nested function is taken. I still don't understand, why is the trampoline overwritten. Can you please explain the reason and a solution to not have this behavioral?

Comment: The trampoline is freed as soon as you return from the function. The first call worked because the freed memory hadn't been overwritten yet. You are trying to write a garbage-collection-requiring construct in C which is not garbage collected. The solution is to redesign to not depend on a garbage collector being there.